# Wordpress error by uploading media files: Missing a temporary folder

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, server, wp-admin

I know there's a lot of similar topics, but none of them is solving my problem.

I just downloaded a website from my computer as localhost to a server. 
The problem is I don't see any of images which were downloaded on the server with WordPress on my local computer. And if I try to upload them directly through the admin panel I get this error:

> Missing a temporary folder.

- I tried configuring `php.ini` and setting a temporary folder for uploads
- I don't have any `public_html` folder
- The permission rights are OKAY
- And also I had another error earlier (but I don't know what happened) uploading to the `wp-content/uploads` folder.

**UPD:** RESOLVED! Just needed to check twice if there is no `;` on the line before `upload_tmp_dir` and if the path to the temporary folder is **written as a string**.

Comment: have you looked into `phpinfo` for `upload_tmp_dir` path?

Comment: @Rizwan, yes I did

Comment: Ok, can you make a simple php script to write a file in that directory using `file_put_contents`? To make sure that directory is writable

Comment: @Rizwan, I would be grateful if you could write this script or post a link to an instruction, because usually I don't work with php, I don't know it well :(

Comment: Oh, you could ask me earlier, I had plenty of time. I would still be happy to help out. Can you send me what `upload_tmp_dir` path is on your server?

Comment: Save this file on server and run it. Let me know what output do you get
https://gist.github.com/mrizwan47/df88b3e49f91e7ac6c27962ff147695b

Comment: Thanks but where exactly should I save this file on server? The structure is:
`var/www/username/data/www/website.com/`

Comment: You can save it anywhere. Root would work. And run like: http://website.com/SO-42656259.php